# What does it mean when there is a number parameter passed to toString?

Tags: javascript, tostring

I'm just wondering what it means to attach a number as a parameter to the `toString()` method

E.g.     `obj.toString(10);`

I googled and i have never seen a parameter before.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The additional parameter works only for [`Number.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString) to specify the radix (integer between 2 and 36 specifying the base to use for representing numeric values):

```
var number = 12345;
number.toString(2) === "11000000111001"
number.toString(3) === "121221020"
// …
number.toString(36) === "9ix"
```

Comment: MDN gives a pretty good explanation on the subject: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Answer (score 15):

This only works on Number objects and is intended to give you a way of displaying a number with a certain radix:

```
var n = 256;
var d = n.toString(10); // decimal: "256"
var o = n.toString(8);  // octal:   "400"
var h = n.toString(16); // hex:     "100"
var b = n.toString(2);  // binary:  "100000000"
var w = n.toString(20); // base 20: "cg"
```

Note that the radix must be an integer between 2 and 36 or `toString()` will raise an error.

Comment: Late comment on this, and it was to short of an edit to make. But `var b = n.toString(16); // binary:  "100000000"` should actually be `n.toString(2)` since binary is in base 2, I assume it was just a copy paste thing!

Comment: @Rchristiani Absolutely. An edit would have been perfectly in order, but now I've changed it myself. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 4):

It's not defined as a globally-applicable argument to `toString`, it only makes sense on `Number`, where it specifies the base to write in. You can use eg. `n.toString(16)` to convert to hex.

The other built-in objects don't use any arguments and JavaScript will silently ignore unused arguments, so passing `16` to any other `toString` method will make no difference. You can of course make your own `toString` methods where optional arguments can mean anything you like.